# Cloudant selector query array field only one get item

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

How can I get only one item when querying an array on CloudantDB?

Example document :

```
"category": {
    "sub_category": [
      {
        "category_id": "127"
      },
      {
        "category_id": "128"
      }
    ],
}
```

query :

```
{
   "selector": {
      "sub_category": {
         "$elemMatch": {
            "category_id": "127"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

wish result document:

```
"category": {
    "sub_category": [
      {
        "category_id": "127"
      }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with Mango queries.  You can accomplish something similar with a combination of a traditional [view](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/ddoc/views.html#db-design-design-doc-view-view-name), and a [show function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/ddoc/render.html#db-design-design-doc-show-show-name).

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy. There is no, array field limitations, convenience like Mongodb.